# How to get single element from $row[id]

Tags: php, mysql

I'm working on a project for PHPBB.  I have a problem that I get some $row types.  And they have some "id"s from MySQL, But I want theese "id"s by one by.

It's SQL query ;

```
$sql = $db->sql_build_query('SELECT', array(
    'SELECT'    => 'u.*, z.friend, z.foe, p.*',

    'FROM'      => array(
        USERS_TABLE     => 'u',
        POSTS_TABLE     => 'p',
    ),

    'LEFT_JOIN' => array(
        array(
            'FROM'  => array(ZEBRA_TABLE => 'z'),
            'ON'    => 'z.user_id = ' . $user->data['user_id'] . ' AND z.zebra_id = p.poster_id'
        )
    ),

    'WHERE'     => $db->sql_in_set('p.post_id', $post_list) . '
        AND u.user_id = p.poster_id'
));

$result = $db->sql_query($sql);
```

And then for user_id's

```
$rowset[$row['post_id']] = array(
        'hide_post'         => ($row['foe'] && ($view != 'show' || $post_id != $row['post_id'])) ? true : false,

        'user_id'           => $row['user_id'],
.
.
```

I logged $row[user_id] for in a topic and it return ;

- 97777
- 97778
- 97779
- 97783

But I want just first id i mean -> "97777" . So how can i pass just "97777" to a variable?

Dont suggest about sql level because I can't change any SQL command.

Comment: if you already know you want 97777 why are querying ?

Comment: *"I can't change any SQL command."* - Why?

Comment: Pretty Unclear. What you want to achieve over here

Comment: The SQL query is very long and has a lot of variables. (phpbb based)
So I can't anything and I didn't put there. For example I mean just first record in $row

Comment: Can you write some code over here?

Comment: I have edited my question. Sorry for first version guys I think it was not good. Please check it now

Answer (score 0):

> Dont suggest about sql level because I can't change any SQL command.

This is the problem though, your PHP is clearly selecting all 9 rows;

Using WHERE `user_id` = '97777' you will only select the record you want.

Why can you not edit the SQL? aren't you familiar with SQL or is the code your are using your own?

Comment: It's phpbb based queries and so complicated.  For example, I want pass just "97777" to any variable. I mean I want first "  $row['post_id']  " element not all elements.

Comment: "It's phpbb based queries and so complicated" if you post it others may not find it complicated; Or do you not know where to find the SQL code?

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself. I have update my question please can u check again?

Answer (score 0):

Without any code it is hard to say what you want to do:

```
reset($row);
$first_key = key($row);
```

or

```
reset($rows);
$first_key = key($rows);
```

Hard to guess without seeing any code.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit your records using LIMIT clause.

```
SELECT column_name FROM table_name LIMIT 1;
```

It will return the first record of that table.